# How to use Cython functions in C/C++ and Python within the same project?

Tags: python, cython

I've been learning about Cython recently. I'm still a beginner, but I'm excited about the prospect of using it in the future.

In my mind, Cython has two main uses:

1. Making Cython or C/C++ functions accessible from Python. See: [*Calling C functions*](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/external.html).

   - You can expose Cython and C/C++ functions to Python by making a Cython module extension using setuptools.
2. Making Cython or Python functions accessible from C/C++. See: [*Embedding Cython modules in C/C++ applications*](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html).

   - You can expose Cython and Python functions to C/C++ by embedding the Python interpreter into your C/C++ application using `Py_Initialize` and company.

---

What if you want to do both of these things for the same project?

Is there a way to use Cython to create a shared object (.so) file which can both be imported as a Python module, and linked against from C/C++?

Comment: I know it is possible via SIP and some frameorks like Qt provide this. But I don’t know about Cython

Comment: I think this should work fine. Just follow the instructions for both parts. I don't they they contradict each other.